# Can someone show me how i can write while statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

how i can write While statement in Mysql. can i write it without create procedure.

Comment: [Can you tell us what you're aiming to do with it?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax

```
WHILE [condition] DO
BEGIN
..code...
END;
END WHILE;
```

**Example:**

```
DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    ...some  code here...
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
```